# How to combine a TextBlock and a Rectangle into 1 element?

Tags: wpf

I'm looking for a way to combine a TextBlock and a Rectangle into 1 element, so I can have 1 click event. I am sure this must be possible, but how?

I'm using Expression Blend, I have tried shift selecting both elements, then right click -> Combine -> Unite, but this didn't seem to have the desired affect.

I might be looking for a way just to wrap the 2 elements in a "holder" element, and then assign the click event to that holder element.

Comment: One would expect more complete / well-formed questions from somebody with 12.4K rep in StackOverflow. What have you tried?

Comment: There is BorderBrush and BorderThickness properties for the Button and that should work for you.

Comment: HighCore: One would expect better answers from somebody with 
17,838 Reputation in StackOverflow. Your answer is relevant in the case of JL but useless for people coming to StackOverflow looking for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I used the group into option from right click context -> grid. Then I assigned a click event to that grid...